# Python CNTK speed comparation of 1bit SGD with normal SGD in 4 GPUs

Tags: python, neural-network, gpu, deep-learning, cntk

I installed version [2.0.beta7](https://cntk.ai/BinaryDrop/CNTK-2-0-beta7-0-Linux-64bit-GPU-1bit-SGD.tar.g) from CNTK in an Azure NC24 GPU VM with Ubuntu (python 3.4).  The machine has 4 NVIDIA K80 GPUs. Build info:

```
            Build type: release
            Build target: GPU
            With 1bit-SGD: yes
            With ASGD: yes
            Math lib: mkl
            CUDA_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-8.0
            CUB_PATH: /usr/local/cub-1.4.1
            CUDNN_PATH: /usr/local
            Build Branch: HEAD
            Build SHA1: 8e8b5ff92eff4647be5d41a5a515956907567126
            Built by Source/CNTK/buildinfo.h$$0 on bbdadbf3455d
            Build Path: /home/philly/jenkins/workspace/CNTK-Build-Linux
```

I was running the CIFAR example in distributed mode:

```
mpiexec -n 4 python TrainResNet_CIFAR10_Distributed.py -n resnet20 -q 32

Finished Epoch [1]: [Training] loss = 1.675002 * 50176, metric = 62.5% * 50176 112.019s (447.9 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [1]: [Training] loss = 1.675002 * 50176, metric = 62.5% * 50176 112.019s (447.9 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [1]: [Training] loss = 1.675002 * 50176, metric = 62.5% * 50176 112.018s (447.9 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [1]: [Training] loss = 1.675002 * 50176, metric = 62.5% * 50176 112.019s (447.9 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [2]: [Training] loss = 1.247423 * 50176, metric = 45.4% * 50176 8.210s (6111.3 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [2]: [Training] loss = 1.247423 * 50176, metric = 45.4% * 50176 8.210s (6111.4 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [2]: [Training] loss = 1.247423 * 50176, metric = 45.4% * 50176 8.210s (6111.8 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [2]: [Training] loss = 1.247423 * 50176, metric = 45.4% * 50176 8.210s (6111.6 samples per second)
...
...
Finished Epoch [160]: [Training] loss = 0.037745 * 49664, metric = 1.2% * 49664 7.883s (6300.4 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [160]: [Training] loss = 0.037745 * 49664, metric = 1.2% * 49664 7.883s (6299.7 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [160]: [Training] loss = 0.037745 * 49664, metric = 1.2% * 49664 7.884s (6299.7 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [160]: [Training] loss = 0.037745 * 49664, metric = 1.2% * 49664 7.884s (6299.2 samples per second)
```

However, when I run it with 1bit SGD I get:

```
mpiexec -n 4 python TrainResNet_CIFAR10_Distributed.py -n resnet20 -q 1 -a 50000

...
Finished Epoch [160]: [Training] loss = 0.059290 * 49664, metric = 2.1% * 49664 10.055s (4939.1 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [160]: [Training] loss = 0.059290 * 49664, metric = 2.1% * 49664 10.056s (4938.9 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [160]: [Training] loss = 0.059290 * 49664, metric = 2.1% * 49664 10.056s (4938.9 samples per second)
Finished Epoch [160]: [Training] loss = 0.059290 * 49664, metric = 2.1% * 49664 10.056s (4938.9 samples per second)
```

As explained [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Multiple-GPUs-and-machines) 1bit should be faster than the normal counterpart. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1-bit sgd is an effective strategy when the communication time between GPUs is large compared to the computation time for a minibatch.

There are two "issues" with your experiment above: the model you are training has few parameters (computation is not that much) and the 4 GPUs are in the same machine (communication is not that bad compared to say going over the network).  <s>Also, inside a machine CNTK uses the [NVIDIA nccl](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nccl) which is much better optimized than a generic MPI implementation that 1-bit uses.</s> **Update:** At the time of this comment NCCL is not used by default.

Comment: Thanks. Therefore, should I see a speed up if I work with a bigger problem (let's say ImageNet with ResNet 152)?

Comment: Yeah that might help though ResNets in general do not have as many parameters as some of the  older nets like VGG that employ fully connected layers at the end.